# update_attributes leads to sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

After this line current_user became nil.
How it is happening?

Params contain:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LH0UlvccEI98ViHuk.....", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"test", "email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this issue by adding

```
attr_accessible :admin
```

in User model.